# GWTP & Singleton

Tags: maven, gwt, singleton, gwtp

I have simple presenter. Announce the call to the class of singleton

```
private RandomString randomString = RandomString.getInstance();
```

When assembling maven I have error

```
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPagePresenter$MyProxy [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:121)]
[INFO] 
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:120)]
[INFO]  -> by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView$Binder [@Inject constructor of by.gwttest.client.client.application.packet.PacketPageView]
[INFO] 
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/DesktopGinjectorProvider.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 8: Failed to resolve 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector' via deferred binding
```

RandomString 
...

```
    private RandomString() {

    }

    private static class RandomStringHolder {
        private final static RandomString instance = new RandomString();
    }

    public static RandomString getInstance() {
        return RandomStringHolder.instance;
    }
...
```

With what it can be connected? Without declaring RandomString project going

Answer (score 0):

Your error is unrelated to the `RandomString`. The error says that you are missing a `@Inject` annotated constructor.

Make sure that your `PacketPageView` and `PacketPagePresenter` have an empty constructor that is annotated with `@Inject`.

```
@Inject
public PacketPagePresenter() {
}
```

Comment: @Inject
 PacketPagePresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {
  super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_SetMainContent);
  init();
 }     Without declaring RandomString project build

Comment: do you use `RandomString` in your `init()`. even if you do so, it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Error was in this code

```
private String convertMStoTime(long millis) {
    //return null;
     return String.format(
     "%02d:%02d:%02d",
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
     - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
     .toHours(millis)),
     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
     - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
     .toMinutes(millis)));
}
```

TimeUnit dont'realese in GWT